# Expand div and play video on click image

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-bg">
    <img class="play-button" src="/play-100x100.png" width="100" height="100" alt="play" title="play">

    <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM" data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM?autoplay=1"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="right-bg">
    <text
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
      $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
      $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
        .appendTo('#wrapper');
    });

  $('.show').live('click',
    function(){
      $('#left-bg').animate(
        {
          'width': '50%'
        },600);
      $('#right-bg').animate(
        {
          'width': '50%'
        },600);
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

What I want is to have a DIV divided in two, so that when clicking on the left DIV it expands to full height and starts playing the video, while closing it with a close button, the video pauses and the left DIV regains its normal height and width.

Comment: Your HTML is broken (the mysterious "<text" tag)

Comment: Check out the youtube iframe api reference: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit fine tuning, but the start is here.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#left-bg').click(
     function() {
       $(this).animate({
         'width': '100%'
       }, 600)
       $('#right-bg').animate({
         'width': '0%'
       }, 600);
       $('.show').fadeIn(600);
     });

   $('.show').on('click', function() {

     $('#left-bg').animate({
       'width': '50%'
     }, 600);
     $('#right-bg').animate({
       'width': '50%'
     }, 600);
     $(this).fadeOut(600);
   });
 });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left-bg,
#right-bg {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.show {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-bg">
    <img class="play-button" src="/play-100x100.png" width="100" height="100" alt="play" title="play">

    <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM" data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM?autoplay=1"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="right-bg">
    sdf
  </div>
  <button class="show">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but it dosnt start playing the video!
what I want is to start playing it on play and then pause on close

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on NiZa answer...
You can use the html5 video poster to display image before user hits the play button..

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls poster="images/image.png">
      <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

You are welcome..